# In $.extend(true, {}, obj) in javascript, what is the purpose of 'true'?

Tags: javascript

When comparing the two constructors:

```
  function C(options, id) {
    this.id = id;

    // Extend defaults with provided options
    this.options = $.extend(true, {}, {
      greeting: 'Hello world!',
      image: null
    }, options);


  };
```

and

```
  function C(params, id) {
    this.$ = $(this);
    this.id = id;

    // Extend defaults with provided options
    this.params = $.extend({}, {
      taskDescription: '',
      solutionLabel: 'Click to see the answer.',
      solutionImage: null,
      solutionText: ''
    }, params);
  }
```

Is the `true` variable necessary after `$.extends`?

Secondly, is the statement `this.$ = $(this)` necessary as the first constructor does not have it and they do the same thing.

Comment: It's necessary when you want the behavior described in the documentation that `true` provides. And `this.$ = $(this);` is necessary if you want that assignment to take place. None of these things are absolutely required. You need to decide what is needed for your code in each circumstance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `true` is necessary if `options` has any nested objects, if you want to make a deep copy of them rather than having the new objects referring to the same nested objects as the originals.

Simple example:

```
var inner = {
    foo: "bar"
};
var outer = {
    inner: inner
};
var shallowCopy = $.extend({}, outer);
var deepCopy = $.extend(true, {}, outer);
console.log(shallowCopy.inner.foo); // "bar"
console.log(deepCopy.inner.foo);    // "bar"
outer.inner.foo = "updated";
console.log(shallowCopy.inner.foo); // "updated"
console.log(deepCopy.inner.foo);    // "bar"
```

Live Copy:

```js
var inner = {
    foo: "bar"
};
var outer = {
    inner: inner
};
var shallowCopy = $.extend({}, outer);
var deepCopy = $.extend(true, {}, outer);
console.log(shallowCopy.inner.foo); // "bar"
console.log(deepCopy.inner.foo);    // "bar"
outer.inner.foo = "updated";
console.log(shallowCopy.inner.foo); // "updated"
console.log(deepCopy.inner.foo);    // "bar"
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

[More in the `$.extend` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/).